# Conditional wait

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following class using synchronized in an attempt to prevent access to a key until it has been generated:

```
public class KeyManager {

  private String key;

  public KeyManager() {
      genKey();
  }

  private void genKey() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
      synchronized(KeyManager.this) {
        public void run() {
          key = operationThatTakesALongTime();
        }
      }
    }).start();
  }

  synchronized public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }

}
```

The problem is that getKey() sometimes gets called before the inner thread and it grabs the lock first.

What I really need is a wait in getKey() that waits only if the key is null. How to do this?

Comment: Looks like lazy initialization applies here, if not full singleton.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Possibly, unless many of this type of object is being used, in which case constructing the key on separate threads will let you initialize multiple objects in the background while doing other things. A lazy instantiation by `getKey()` would serialize key creation. Of course, having separate threads per key manager at a higher level could make that a non-issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) instead of reimplementing the logic.

I would also probably avoid starting a new Thread from the constructor, because it can lead to subtle concurrency bugs - instead you can simply make the `genKey` method public and add the relevant javadoc (this method must be called first blabla):

```
public class KeyManager {

  private volatile boolean genStarted = false;
  private final CountDownLatch keyGenerated = new CountDownLatch(1);
  private String key;

  public void genKey() {
    genStarted = true;
    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
      public void run() {
        key = operationThatTakesALongTime();
        keyGenerated.countDown();
      }
    }).start();
  }

  public String getKey() throws InterruptedException {
    if (!genStarted) throw new IllegalStateException("you must run genKey first");
    keyGenerated.await();
    return key;
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach works but is a bit odd for a couple of reasons. 1) Standard monitor wait/notify is sufficient, and 2) the field names are a bit confusing, as `generating` remains `true` even after the key has been generated -- code should be as self-documenting as possible.

Comment: @JasonC re 1) I don't necessarily agree - the latch approach is shorter (ok very slightly) and the risk of a bug is smaller than using wait/notify. I actually don't see any reasons to use wait/notify when you can find another way based on the concurrent package. Re 2) agreed and amended.

Comment: +1 Yes it does produce some nice short code, doesn't it. I never really thought of using a `CountDownLatch` for that; I think I will also start recommending it when people ask about this type of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Mhm

```
synchronized public long getKey() 
{
    while (key == null) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            wait(); 
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException e) 
        { 
            /* handle here */ 
        } 
    }
    return key;
}
```

`wait` will let the thread to release the lock, then could take it again when `notify` is called. If key is still null it will release the lock again.

But i think it's not the best way to do this.

It throws `InterruptedException`.

Comment: This is actually a very reasonable way to do this. `InterruptedException`s should be handled as appropriate, e.g.: `while (key == null) { try { wait(); } catch (InterruptedException x) { ... } }`, where the handler either ignores or aborts depending on the desired behavior. (Or don't handle it and just let it throw, if that is the desired effect).

Comment: Yes, i should admit i didn't catch it in the example because i remember later the exception. :(